# 3d model misses the effect of animation feature after saving in powerpoint 2016

Tags: animation, 3d, powerpoint

I added a 3d model into powerpoint 2016 and added some animations on the 3d model. The animations work well. However, after I save the slides, the 3d animation (e.g., turntable) is gone. It seems after the saving, the 3d model changes to an image. however, if I rotate the 3d model, the animation come back again.

Anyone know why this happens?